# I can't get the led to change its blinking rate with the potentiometer for an atmega328p

Tags: c++, embedded, atmega

I can't get the led connected to pin 5 to change its blink rate when the potentiometer changes. I am not sure if it is the way I set up the times, I used this code about 2 months ago and I remember it working fine. I also don't remember changing anything to make it stop working. Please any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
 
volatile double adc_value;
volatile unsigned long my_millis;  
unsigned long entry_time_1 = 0;
unsigned long entry_time_2 = 0;
int PD4_state = 0;
int PD5_state = 0;
 
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)                    
{                                          
  my_millis++;                          
}                                          
 
ISR(ADC_vect)
{
  adc_value = ADC;
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
}



void blink_PD4()
{
  if (my_millis - entry_time_1 >= 500)
  {
    entry_time_1 = my_millis;
    if (PD4_state == 0)
    {
      PD4_state = 1;
      PORTD |= (1<<PORTD4);
    }
    else
    {
      PD4_state = 0;
      PORTD &= ~(1<<PORTD4);
    }
  }
}
 
void blink_PD5_without_mapping()
{
  if (my_millis - entry_time_2 > adc_value)
  {
    entry_time_2 = my_millis;
    if (PD5_state == 0)
    {
      PD5_state = 1;
      PORTD |= (1<<PORTD5);
    }
    else
    {
      PD5_state = 0;
      PORTD &= ~(1<<PORTD5);
    }
  }
}
 
void blink_PD5_with_mapping()
{
  if (my_millis - entry_time_2 >= adc_value/1023*400+100)
  //(((((double)adc_value)/1023)*400)+100))
  {
    entry_time_2 = my_millis;
    if (PD5_state == 0)
    {
      PD5_state = 1;
      PORTD |= (1<<PORTD5);
    }
    else
    {
      PD5_state = 0;
      PORTD &= ~(1<<PORTD5);
    }
  }
}
 
int main(void)
{
  
 
  DDRD = (1<<PORTD5)|(1<<PORTD4);
  TCCR0A = (1<<WGM01);          
  TCCR0B = 0b00000000;          
  TIMSK0 = (1<<OCIE0A);        
  OCR0A = 249;                    
 
  TCCR0B = (1<<CS01) | (1<<CS00);

  ADMUX = 0b01000011;  
  ADCSRA = 0b10101111;
  ADCSRB = 0b00000000;
  
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);



  sei();
  while(1)        
  {
    blink_PD4();
    //blink_PD5_without_mapping();
    blink_PD5_with_mapping();
 
   
  }
}
```

Comment: Problems with this code include non-atomic access to multibyte shared variables, unnecessary use of glory bal variables, unnecessary and Ill-advised use of floating point code.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The frequency of the blinking remains unchanged? Or it doesn't blink at all?